# Объединить синонимичные метки {“web”, “веб”, ...}

Tags: предложение, статус-завершено, метки, синонимы-меток

Объединить:

- [web](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web) - 881 вопрос;
- [веб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1) - 99 вопросов.

(по состоянию на 17.03.2017)

Эти метки нужно объединить, так как есть устойчивая тенденция использования как первой, так и второй в одном и том же смысле.

Также существует симметричные множества:

- [web-service](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-service) - 33 вопроса;
- [веб-сервисы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b) - 48 вопросов;
- [веб-служба](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b1%d0%b0) - 4 вопроса.

---

- [web-design](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-design) - 17 вопросов;
- [веб-дизайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd) - 49 вопросов.

Comment: Две пары надо смёрджить в одну тройку, не?

Comment: @Qwertiy , видимо да. Я не знаю, чем тут синонимы отличаются от "смёрдживания".

Comment: Я имел в виду, что в вопросе должно быть не 4 пары, а 2 пары и одна тройка

Comment: @Qwertiy А, ну да, я сам это только сейчас заметил.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

Сделать такую синонимизацию:

- [web](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web), [веб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1) ⇒ [веб-программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)
- [web-service](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-service), [веб-сервисы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b) ⇒ [веб-служба](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b1%d0%b0)
- [web-design](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-design) ⇒ [веб-дизайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd)

Comment: Давайте уже синонимизируйте!

Comment: @alexolut done!

Answer (score -2):

Сделать такую синонимизацию:

- [web](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web), [веб](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1), [web-service](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-service), [веб-служба](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%bb%d1%83%d0%b6%d0%b1%d0%b0) и [веб-сервисы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b) => [веб-программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5)
- [web-design](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/web-design) => [веб-дизайн](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%b4%d0%b8%d0%b7%d0%b0%d0%b9%d0%bd)

И обязательно **добавить описание**. Если первое ещё относительно очевидно (хотя и общо), то второе для StackOverflow *на грани оффтопика*, т. к. мы здесь обсуждаем не дизайнерские аспекты веба, а технические, скорее вёрстку чем дизайн. Но синонимизировать эти метки к вёрстке это права тем не менее не даёт.

---

Решение свалить столько меток в [веб-программирование](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d0%bf%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b3%d1%80%d0%b0%d0%bc%d0%bc%d0%b8%d1%80%d0%be%d0%b2%d0%b0%d0%bd%d0%b8%d0%b5) мне видится сомнительным, но чисто интуитивно. Я не могу определить отдельную тематику для [веб-сервисы](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/%d0%b2%d0%b5%d0%b1-%d1%81%d0%b5%d1%80%d0%b2%d0%b8%d1%81%d1%8b), не занимаемую другими метками ([http](https://ru.stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/http), например). Но предлагаемые синонимы в этом ответе я менять уже не буду, чтобы не ломать голосование.

Comment: Осталось кому-то поручить описание )

Comment: веб-службы/сервисы - я бы оставил отдельно, как-никак это цельное самостоятельно понятие .

Comment: @Nofate у меня тоже некоторые сомнения по этому поводу, но я сходу не смог придумать ни одного вопроса, хорошо относящегося к одному, но не к другому.

Comment: Ну, скажем _"Какой способ идентификации анонимных пользователей мне применить?"_  или _"Пишу на коленке свой JWT"_ - это про веб-программирование, а _"Как мне оборачивать исключения в коды ошибок"_ - это про веб-сервисы, скорее. (Все примеры вымышлены, совпадения случайны, организация запрещенная в РФ).

Comment: Но т.к. веб-сервисы входят в веб-программирование - ситуации могут быть неоднозначные, конечно.

Comment: @Nofate ну, отношение включения для меток штука обычная, но то, что вы привели к веб-сервисам, мне больше намекает на [tag:http]. Даже не знаю. Предложите свой вариант отдельным ответом что ли.

Comment: А мой ответ совпадает с ТС.

Comment: @Nofate а, точно. но соответствующий этому ответ всё равно был бы полезен, чтобы принять :)

Comment: @D-side веб-сервисы - это SOAP и семейство стандартов WS-*

Comment: @PavelMayorov понятно, что как понятие они существуют (и перечисленное лишь небольшой кусочек). Но хорошего примера вопроса для этой метки, чтобы эта метка не была "сбоку" (т. е. не указывала на обстоятельства, а именно дополняла контекст проблемы) я не увидел.

Comment: @D-side "Как правильно передать стек ошибки в конверте SOAP 1.1 при использовании WS-Security, чтобы этот стек тоже был подписан?"

Comment: @PavelMayorov вот об этом "сбоку" и я говорил. Это вопрос скорее к метке [tag:soap]. [tag:веб-сервисы] никакого контекста не добавляет.

Comment: @D-side нее, это вопрос не про soap, а про ws-security. Тут скорее soap сбоку...

Comment: @PavelMayorov ну, вы с тех пор поправили коммент :) Но [tag:веб-сервисы] так и так сбоку. [tag:ws-security] к месту, да. Но, повторюсь, WS-* это лишь небольшой кусок мира веб-сервисов. Отводить эту метку только им мне видится неправильным.

Comment: @PavelMayorov а, извините, не поправили. Это я прочитал только кусок в уведомлении. Мой косяк ._. Вывод, тем не менее, не меняется.